# competitive equilibrium with density functions

Tags: microeconomics

Assume there are two competitive markets for goods a and b. Each consumer will either purchase one unit of a and none of b, or one of b and none of a. Consumers never consume both goods. Utilities are as follows:

$u(x,t) = 1.25 - 0.4t$

$u(y,t) = - (t-0.6)^2$

Valuations are for single units.

Assume the consumers are uniformly distributed over the interval [0.6,1.6] and in the initial allocation of goods, each with $0.6 \leq t \leq 1$ owns a unit of x and each with $t$ in $1.1 \leq t \leq 1.6$ own one unit of y. Find the competitive equilibrium.

What is throwing me off here is how to include the probability density of the initial distribution of goods.

Comment: I would take an expectation over their initial allocations when generating their demand functions.